# Sharepoint: find out if current user belongs to specified group

Tags: sharepoint

How can I find out programmatically if current user belongs to some group on sharepoint website?
I need it because I would like to show a different content for the users belonging to one group.

Comment: Using the SharePoint API or web services?

Comment: Question was already asked here >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063931/sharepoint-check-if-a-user-is-member-of-a-group

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I stumbled upon your post because I have (IMHO) the exact same question, but the replies seem somehow not to match that. So I went on searching and found http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=30460140&threadid=30420861:

```
SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPGroup managerGroup = site.Groups["SP_Project_Manager"];
bool isManager = site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(managerGroup);
```

As of 2013, according to s654m's comment, the signature seems to have changed:

```
bool isManager = site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(managerGroup.ID);
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work in 2013 web parts... this however does:
SPWeb site = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPGroup managerGroup = site.Groups["SP_Project_Manager"];
bool isManager = site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(managerGroup.ID);

Comment: @s654m - thank you for the notice, I have incorporated it in my answer.

Comment: Crazy thing, my account is the right one and belong to my admin group, but the boolean returned by `site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(7)` is always false. Thus it's the good id and I displayed the current user, it's the good one too. Any hint ?

Answer (score 3):

maybe this [code sample pos](http://forums.asp.net/p/1012092/1353022.aspx)t in the ASP.NET Forums helps.

A method you could use

```
/// <summary>
/// This private method get users by selected SPGroup object.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="group">SPGroup object</param>

private void UsersList(SPGroup group)
{
           foreach(SPUser singleUser in group.Users)
           {
                       foreach(SPRole singleRole in singleUser.Roles)
                       {
                                   _usersListCollection.Add(new UserListCollection(
                                   singleUser.LoginName,singleRole.Name,group.ParentWeb.Title));
                       }
           }
}
```

Good luck,
Henrik

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach that kind of issues is to find inspiration at Codeplex. The quality of the code that people have released is usually very good.

I am sure that you can find the solution here: http://accesschecker.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hey there, I work on SharePoint

If you have MOSS installed you might take a look at the 'audiences' functionality, that allows you to target different folks without code.